# Unbound classpath container

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm a beginner with Android development. I have source code for an app and when I import it into eclipse I get the error 
`Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [Android API 19 Platform]' in project 'Material Libs'`

How can I fix this?

Comment: You might want to use android studio instead. Eclipse is now a second class citizen of the Android tooling project so learning how to develop for Android using it is not really that good in the long run. Besides, Android studio is far easier to work with.